# Checking for "triplicates" strings in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, similarity

trying to find the best way to check for **triplicates values** inside an array of strings.
I found many stackoverflow solutions for **duplicates values** which is not the case in here.
This is the farest i could get with solving this and I am not sure if it is the correct way:

```
const array = [
    "peace",
    "peace",
    "Vrede",
    "Patz",
    "Salam",
    "paz",
    "Salam",
    "Salam"
  ];

  const findTriplicates = (param) => {
    let counts = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
      if (counts[param[i]]) {
        counts[param[i]] += 1;
      } else {
        counts[param[i]] = 1;
      }
    }
    for (let i in counts) {
      if (counts[i] === 3) {
        console.log(i + " exists " + counts[i] + " times.");
      }
    }
  };

  findTriplicates(array); // Salam exists 3 times.
```

please don't hesitate to **fix my code** or to post **your solution**.
thanks for your support in advance :)
Cheerz!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Cause it seems that the code works.

Comment: You should not do `counts[i] === 3` if you also want to detect "more or equal than three" (which i'd expect, but you don't say).

Comment: @Reyno thanks for your comment, I am not sure if my solution is the correct way.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I agree then it should be `counts[i] > 2`, but to not make my question complicated I edited the title to "only triplicates".

Comment: Well *"correct"* is completely open for interpretation and might differ for every developer. This will result in [opinion based](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions) questions/answers which are not allowed. I suggest posting your question on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you're looking for improvements.

Comment: Additionally, questionable choices, some style, some borderline problematic: prototype and special properties - for `counts`, use a `Map` instead of an object (or at least `Object.create(null)`), and no `for ... in`. This is to add additional guards against prototype-pollution, and existing accessor prototype properties like "\_\_proto\_\_". If you iterate the entire array, and don't need the index apart from indexing the current element, use `for (const item of array) /*...*/` (personal opinion on modern style).

Answer (score 0):

Your overall idea is good, using Hash Maps (js objects) is the best option for the task.

You can move your "=== 3" check to the first loop and have another object to save triplicates, it will be twice faster.

Comment: That would falsely identify quadruplicates and above as triplets. Also, it is slower since you are more frequently checking for === 3 or at least be kinda equivalent. If I am not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
  const findTriplicates = (param) => {
  let values = [...new Set(param)];
  let triples = [];

  values.forEach(item=>{
    let counter = 0;
    param.forEach(s=>{
      if(s===item) counter++;
    })
    if(3==counter) triples.push(item);
  })

  return triples;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way to do things like this. You can always optimize or sacrifice performance for readability, but that is up to the developer.

I changed nothing about the functionality in findTriplicates, but the code is very different.

findTriplicates2 works a little different but is by no means superior

```js
const array = [
  "peace",
  "peace",
  "Vrede",
  "Patz",
  "Salam",
  "paz",
  "Salam",
  "Salam"
];

const findTriplicates = (param) => {
  let counts = param.reduce((acc, p) => {
    acc[p] ? acc[p]++ : acc[p] = 1
    return acc;
  }, {})
  Object.keys(counts).forEach((key) => counts[key] === 3 &&
    console.log(`${key} exists 3 times.`)
  );
};

findTriplicates(array); // Salam exists 3 times.

const findTriplicates2 = (param) => {
  let triples = [...new Set(param)].reduce((acc, item) => {
    let counter = param.reduce((acc2, s) => {
      if (s === item) acc2++;
      return acc2;
    }, 0);
    if (3 == counter) acc.push(item);
    return acc;
  }, [])

  triples.forEach((triple) => console.log(`${triple} exists 3 times.`));
};

findTriplicates2(array); // Salam exists 3 times.
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an object to keep count of how many times the string repeats and then iterate through each element in the array while updating the count in the object. Then you filter through that object for any values equal to 3.

```js
const array = [
  'peace',
  'peace',
  'Vrede',
  'Patz',
  'Salam',
  'paz',
  'Salam',
  'Salam',
];

// Object to keep count of each word
const countObj = {};

// Iterate through the array to get the count for each word
array.forEach((element) => {
  // Does word exist in the count object? if so -> add 1 to its count, else -> add word and count 1 to the object
  countObj[element] ? (countObj[element] += 1) : (countObj[element] = 1);
});

// Filter out keys that appear exactly 3 times and print them them
const filteredArray = Object.keys(countObj).filter(
  (key) => countObj[key] === 3
);

console.log(filteredArray); // Salam
```